# Good neuroscience research blogs

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, experimental-neuroscience

In the field of AI research there are really good research blogs that regularly analyse methods and review papers. Examples that come to mind are:

1. [BAIR blog](https://bair.berkeley.edu/blog/): The Berkeley AI Research blog
2. [Distill](https://distill.pub/): an AI journal devoted to clear explanations

Might there be something similar for neuroscience? To qualify what I mean by 'good' the blog would have to cover:

- methods for experimental, computational and theoretical neuroscience
- comprehensive reviews of basic neuroscience research

Three neuroscience blogs that come to mind are:

1. [Harvard Neuro Blog](https://www.harvardneuroblog.com/): articles from graduate students and postdocs working on basic research in the neurosciences at Harvard University
2. [Neuwrite West Blog](https://neuwritewest.squarespace.com/): a blog to make neuroscience accessible to anyone curious about the brain
3. [Niko Kriegeskorte's blog](https://nikokriegeskorte.org/): the blog of the visual scientist Niko Kriegeskorte

So far, I am unaware of an online journal like Distill for neuroscience research.

**Note:** As per the suggestion of Arnon Weinberg I decided to qualify what exactly I mean by 'good' and provided examples for concreteness.

Comment: The Neuroskeptic blog is a nice one. 

Comment: -1 This seems like a long lists of opinions and not a good fit for the SE model.

Comment: @AidanRocke I think just removing the word "Good" from the title would alleviate many fears of opinion-based answers.  Edit the question to specify criteria for "good" instead.

Comment: @StrongBad You can join [the discussion on meta](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2459/21) on whether or not such question are appropriate for this site. The current consensus seems that this particular question is an example of a good 'list' question.

Answer (score 2):

Also check:
https://bitsandbrains.io/
https://www.talyarkoni.org/blog/
calling it a blog is too much but sometimes we share stuff:
[kordinglab.com](http://kordinglab.com/about/)

But also, there is maybe a bit more of a culture of publishing thoughts in papers in the field.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to plug

Markus Meister’s blog: https://markusmeister.com

Jeremy Borniger’s blog and journal club: https://jeremyborniger.com/new-blog

The Spike on Medium curated by Mark Humphries and curated by others; probably the closest to what you are looking for: https://medium.com/the-spike

Inscopix’s corporate blog: https://media.inscopix.com

Off the Convex Path which features ML and computational neuroscience: https://www.offconvex.org

And Richard Gao’s blog: http://www.rdgao.com/blog/

None of them are “one-stop-shops” like some machine learning blogs but they all offer interesting perspectives and reviews across computational and systems neuroscience.